# Lossless VP9 Webm Encoding of PNG Sequence with Alpha in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, webm, alpha-channel, vp9

I'm trying to encode a sequence of 32-bit 8bpc PNG images (RGB with an alpha channel) using the lossless VP9 codec with ffmpeg; specifically:

`ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i out%04d.png -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 -pix_fmt yuva420p output.webm`

This seems to encode the video losslessly; however, when I run:

`ffmpeg -i output.webm out%04d.png`

the resulting PNG images that it spits out are **missing the alpha channel (they are 24 bit, 8bpc)!** What's going wrong here?

These are the files that I'm testing this on if you want to try it for yourself:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IKThU4X_Ub1IqW-pnhds4Z_KwQEwUMtK

If it helps, I'm using this build of ffmpeg on Windows 10:

````
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100```
````

Comment: The conversion form RGB to YUV is not lossless. You are losing data even before you get to VP9.

Comment: @szatmary, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The native VP9 decoder does not support alpha, so the VPX decoder has to be forced.

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i output.webm out%04d.png
```